# How do you reinforce round deck footings?

Tags: footings, rebar

I'm building a covered deck on some weak soil (clay/sandy clay). I'm going to use 24" round footings that I was planning on reinforcing with a bunch of left over rebar. How can I effectively reinforce my footings? My though was to just  cut a few lengths and tie them together using wire in an tic tac toe grid. Is there a better way to do it?

I've dug my holes 5ft deep and prep'd the ground by laying fabric in the bottom, then pouring in gravel and road crush and tamping it all down.

Comment: You might want to calculate how much concrete you need for a hole 24" round and 5' deep and make sure they really need to be that big (those are massive holes requiring around 24 bags of 80lb concrete _each_ ).

Comment: @JPhi1618 I'm putting a 10" pier on top of my footing. The footing is only going to be ~10" deep. A 5', 24" pile would be silly.

Comment: Ok, I guess I don't understand what you meant about digging the holes 5' deep.

Answer (score 1):

Really there's no need the footings will not see any tensile or flexing loads.

Be sure to tie the posts into the footing. That's all that's needed. if the post is being embedded in the concrete you could pass some bar through it (drill a hole).

Answer (score 0):

The pattern of the rebar is not to critical as long as you have enough of it and it is all tied together. I usually make a cage, 4 stick of vertical RB tied together with horizontal pieces, both near the top and bottom. The vertical RB needs to be far enough apart to allow the post bracket to be set in the concrete. For 24" you may want more then 4 vertical or an inner cage and an out cage.

5 feet down is good ( *unless code for your area dictates deeper* ) and  24" footings is more then enough for a deck, 12" would be OK and 16 would be big enough. Even though you have the holes already dug  You can go with the smaller sonotube and back fill around them, compact the back fill well.

Comment: The 24" footing is only going to be ~10" tall. I'm putting a 10" pier on top of that.

Comment: What ?   your stated  in your question that you dug holes 5 feet deep ??  If the deck is attached to the house then you need to be below the frost line. You need to know what the code is for frost line in your area. The ground moves up and down from season to season. If your deck is not attached to the house then your plan is ok as it can move freely. *EDIT your question to have the correct info or the answers may/will not apply*.

Comment: They are... My footings are 24" round footings below frost depth, they are supporting a 10" pier.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how good you want it.

Typical would be to bend L shaped bars to tie footing to column, with the foot of the L radial, and tie rings (a fancier bending job) or octagons to those radials. You can do it with a mesh/grid instead, but it won't do quite as good of a job. You should still have bent bars connecting the two parts.